# Recharts data doesn't load unless I hit ctrl+s

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vite, recharts, swc-compiler

I created a `LineChart` using recharts and I'm pulling data using `axios` from a `db.json` file hosted locally by json-server. Every time I load the page or reload the chart doesn't show up. Only when I hit `ctrl+s` to save my file and trigger re-render does the chart show up. How do I get the chart to show up on initial page load?

I used `Vite` with `SWC` to initialize the project and versions are: `react@18.2.0`, `vite@4.4.3`, `recharts@2.7.2`

Chart code:

```
<ResponsiveContainer width="100%" height={270}>
        <LineChart
          width={600}
          height={300}
          data={monthlyData}
          margin={{
            left: -20,
          }}
        >
          <CartesianGrid vertical={false} />
          <Tooltip />
          <XAxis axisLine={false} dataKey="name" tickSize={0} tickMargin={10} />
          <YAxis
            axisLine={false}
            domain={[0, maxY]}
            tickCount={maxY / 100 + 1}
            tickSize={0}
            tickMargin={10}
          />
          <Line
            type="monotone"
            dataKey="user"
            strokeWidth={2}
            stroke="#9BDD7C"
            dot={false}
          />
          <Line
            type="monotone"
            dataKey="guest"
            strokeWidth={2}
            stroke="#E9A0A0"
            dot={false}
          />
        </LineChart>
      </ResponsiveContainer>
```

This is how I'm fetching the data:

```
const getActivity = async (index) => {
    const res = await api.get("/activity");
    const data = res?.data;
    setYearlyData(data);
    setMonthlyData(yearlyData[index]);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getActivity(0);
  }, []);
```

Comment: Not enough information. Most likely you have a reactivity bug unrelated to recharts which is not being shown here.

Comment: I added in the function that fetches the data. Also, `yearlyData` and `monthlyData` are the only state variables I'm using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setMonthlyData(yearlyData[index])` is wrong.

When you do `const [yearlyData, setYearlyData] = useState([])`, `yearlyData` is *immutable*. What `setYearlyData` does is not change `yearlyData`, but make it so that the next time your component runs, it will read the new value for `yearlyData`. It will also queue up your component to run (i.e. re-render) when the browser gets the chance.

That means that *at this time* `yearlyData` is still undefined. You should use `setMonthlyData(data[index])` if you want to use the data you just got.

BTW this issue can be avoided if you make the initial state of `yearlyData` `null`. Then JavaScript will let you know there is an error with `yearlyData[index]`.

If I guessed this issue wrong, you can try to debug further by inserting

```js
console.log('yearlyData', yearlyData)
console.log('monthlyData', monthlyData)
```

after your `useState`, and change your `getActivity` to:

```js
const getActivity = async (index) => {
  console.log('fetching')
  const res = await api.get("/activity");
  const data = res?.data;
  console.log('data', data)
  setYearlyData(data);
  console.log('yearlyData', yearlyData)
  setMonthlyData(yearlyData[index]);
};
```

That should show you what's going on.

Comment: Thank you! Helped to improve my understanding of state variables.